# Best Practice to Send large data from server to mobile app

Tags: android, ios, mysql, sqlite, server

I am trying to find out the best method to sync data from server to mobile devices just like the initial syncing of WhatsApp. I have to implement the same for both iOS and Android. I found a method to send as files but not able to find a reliable method. I am using MySQL database and mobile developers uses SQLite DB and it is not possible to create SQLite database file as query output which might be able to use directly by mobile developers.

I am searching for the answer of the following:

1. Is it possible to send data as files from server to mobile app without losing the data? If so, what is the best file format that can be used?
2. If file transfer is not a good method, which method has to be used? I have used both JSON and XML format but this is about large amount of data like a backup.

Comment: So, are you saying that the mobile client *cannot* download a SQLite database file exported from MySQL?

Comment: Sqlite database can be sync to mobile devices but I cannot find a solution to create Sqlite DB dump from Mysql Database. I mean using coding..not manually creating...

Answer (score 0):

Json is best to do that. You have to split the data into many parts, then you have to get data from your mobile one by one after a successful retrieval.

For a simple method, you can use Realm Database to do it automatically. 
https://blog.realm.io/realm-for-android

Comment: So transferring as files is not a usual methods...I have to sync large data.. like a chat history of 6 months

Comment: Syncing data is always a critical one, that's why I suggest you implement **Realm Database** for this type of requirement.

Comment: I have to sync only initially ie, when a user changes the device or login after a long time. Realm sync data each time I send data to server. I don't need this since it can slow down the chat process.